# Why does template not discard the co_return?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine, c++-templates

I'd like to make a function with both sync and coroutine version, without using template specialization, i.e. with an `if constexpr`.

This is the function I wrote:

```
template <Async _a>
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  if constexpr (_a == Async::Disable)
    return a;
  else
    co_return a;
}
```

But when I instantiate the true branch it gives an error

```
auto a = func<Async::Disable>(1); // compiler error
auto b = func<Async::Enable>(2);  // ok
```

```
error: unable to find the promise type for this coroutine
```

Why is this not working?

[Full code with an implementation of the promise type](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGEgGykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCD%2BAOykAA6oCoRODB7evgGp6ZkCoeFRLLHxSbaY9o4CQgRMxAQ5Pn5cgXaYDlkNTQQlkTFxCckKjc2teR22EwNhQ%2BUjSQCUtqhexMjsHOYAzHhUWFQA1AD6Z8gGRhcmGgCC%2B2FXXlgnJntumKopcXhsgjEAHo0MQNo5wh9sHd7sw2AoUkxtidxugYSZElYHicTl4MkYTnDMAikZgUQR0CAQN9fsR/oxGrQPljHokACLosx7GpKTkHBgvN4fNyg8ELKF81yHPnPbxCz5eRy0QgATwlDyeArlZOFBBVvzOBGITEICnVjy5steOs%2ByFRyui5phjB8JyuTAUChO9wUKoF6MxMJxbLwCiY0Xo7z2bJOGlIQZO2GYEcw8Y17OZ6IeRJJyKwjToAZZOIImBYKQMpajbj1vyJJwAKuaceNiF4HN7fQKAErEry0AjvQPYnHktsdlJglihzCG/U64f3Uejn1%2B5C9hT9wfATAEM7EXebBhnVDRbTdAgQFZDiwnA8EI83ggIUMYjl7W9vhPLpiK1AnMJMjEM5NwRVwrxvO9D2IBhyUpEBQLrdAznCAA3OIMSsDMPyHDkRx/P8ThoZhaBAvEkIghhUG%2BbYUkHTCoIfGC4KpRDXBQzB0OITCvxwr98OXd4BJxVDUDwdBcQYBBDHQehkJozA6KyCCGPDEhLxWZlcO/UdRPExijzOVCxC8TAIAbE5VGvHjhNHA9NwHM4AFooXsrczijGNVEzWz%2BKXQTVx7PsBxOAAqNzHJ8/ycV44sVy7ddgsvSdUGnJQ51%2BUKTknazMWy4gPI%2BGNJy0ydnNcpLCujE5n1fPiMwEwLEocy8mo3LdzH8Tq71y29aoUFy9mwMrPLvAA6MqtOICaCtGhh%2B1oOjuJwsrBuwCK91G/qtL85c2qS7rUFpJgiGWtkIH2lrOu64hepql8BqhEaivGyacOm57qvm2hFqNUqCrWjaqpjbb3ug2DQtBz8Guik5olQTwTiYAB3E09wPJh0BVCC0AYcZCWo1RaPovL70fI1TJ2mHlx00ty0rTBdXnes5GbXSxIklG0bIsCGHQCBUSpUVFQWM5pL5%2BhhVZoaTgQO7dtHCyucIfc%2BzYSjCeJyCyeYwWQBYVB0IgIHNPqvDYZStLZ1rMlQreuKcQsoGopi7CWQTOmKxOm0a2Z1gyQbUhOzXJG2dbdtB0u9yCCij2yy9qsmbrf3GzDimOyjxyY8%2BQPg4FKkQzDFM2Zs2G8TCYAavnUamw/BNYrj%2BnverG361r6ER3DjOEvarPhVzpqqSTcNJaG%2BvF2XcuCRt0bM%2Bztx25d7S641dN31vIEgUJf3czJfMTSZVf7k9hmW79thGyDprziYc0p8ruetvPvfdwPqk58Nfug7OW%2BhqpG3Y4PBPs3YU18f7mjnsKMIBBv6/2wERLwAoIDQKRr1BMhw3QCHGDSYgJwIA/08i9QeIBC4j0wJpASOtYK/zijyRmAk0CqyYtQ2OMMYQoJYCaBgKkJ4nE3kjQiTBRpUEQcgMwoCEoF1DGQqEEAuCmw3lvNA5Y6BxBOHEME3ERy/iIHDYRoiJFriHsmUe2AIBmAUQGc2HA1i0E4AAVl4H4DgWhSCoE4G4aw1gUQbC2DqLkPBSAEE0DYtYABrEAkgACcY0olRP8HE/w/g9hRL2Mk6QdiOCSCcSEtxnBeAKBAHGYJLibGkDgLAJAyiUiqLIBQCA1TakgGAFwLgZg%2BB0FLMQQpEBoi5OiGEJoKpOCBOUQCAgAB5BgtBhmlNIFgThRhxBzPwAeHo6FClzO%2BN0RUOxXHQJqLkh0xpiAqg8FgEZvAjT/EuWsKgBhgAKAAGp4EwMjCZdZLkyEECIMQ7ApDfPkEoNQuTdBcH0IYYwXjLD6DwNEQpkA1hHTqHjTgTknKoiKqYSw1gzBCKclQYWEJiQnCcmyIQchlDKAmd2BsZx7hCAAJoRDcAUmoF4sguD5lMPwKSgh80GGUCoIAAAcBQMgop5SAPlaQJVZEFcMeIYqug9HqHMKVfKVUor6M0BVSwlWzH6BqqJhrdULCFSMEVawFC%2BO2HoI0mAdg8FsQ4nJcz3EcFUCK/wTl/CSBOMAZAyATitLGmYPBnicUwsTPgU67wAlBw8Co%2BguD9jyKuSElY4SQD2I0GNDQGg9gFr2GkjQySkngsydk0gLAJAFtIM41xHqClFKCZml1HAzBuqbfkttpSs2kC4hkZwkggA%3D)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The standard explicitly says this is not possible. As per Note 1 in [stmt.return.coroutine#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.return.coroutine#1)

> ... A coroutine shall not enclose a return statement ([stmt.return]).
>
> [Note 1: For this determination, it is irrelevant whether the return statement is enclosed by a discarded statement ([stmt.if]). — end note]

So you won't be able to return from a coroutine even if it's in a discarded statement. You can specialize the function template instead of using `if constexpr`.

```
template <Async _a>
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) 
{
    co_return a;
}

template <>
AsyncResult<int, Async::Disable> func<Async::Disable>(int a) 
{
    return a;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/46cfh9deT).

Answer (score 3):

A function which has a `co_return`/`co_await`/`co_yield` statement in it is unconditionally a coroutine, even if it is discarded by `if constexpr`.

You will have to have 2 different functions. Here are some things you could do:

```cpp
// Have the second function be a lambda:
template <Async _a>
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  if constexpr (_a == Async::Disable)
    return a;
  else
    return ([](int a) -> AsyncResult<int, _a> {
      co_return a;
    })(a);
}
```

```cpp
// Have the second function be a helper function
namespace detail {
AsyncResult<int, Async::Enable> async_enable_func(int a) {
  co_return a;
}
}

template <Async _a>
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  if constexpr (_a == Async::Disable)
    return a;
  else
    return detail::async_enable_func(a);
}
```

```cpp
// Have the second function be an overload
template <Async _a> requires (_a == Async::Disable)
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  return a;
}

template <Async _a> requires (_a == Async::Enable)
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  co_return a;
}
```

```cpp
// Since you only have 1 template parameter, you can fully specialize
template<Async _a>
AsyncResult<int, _a> func(int a) {
  return a;
}

template<>
AsyncResult<int, Async::Enable> func<Async::Enable>(int a) {
  co_return a;
}
```